# Trim Excel cells that meet certain criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
row_number = 6
Do
DoEvents
    row_number = row_number + 1
    item_description = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row_number)
        If InStr(item_description, "Direct Credit") > 0 Then
        item_description = ActiveCell.Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = Right(ActiveCell, Len(ActiveCell) - 21)
        End If
Loop Until item_description = B1000

End Sub
```

Hi,

I need to trim first 21 characters if the specific cell starts with "Direct Credit"?
There is something wrong in my coding after "Then" in If...
Can Some one help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()
Dim c As Range
     For Each c In Range("B6:B1200")
         With c
             If Left(.Value, 13) = "Direct Credit" Then .Value = Right(.Value, Len(.Value) - 21)
         End With
     Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Usually it is helpful to include some text which explains how the code answers the question or solves the problem in addition to bare code.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps. If so please mark the answer as answered.

```
Public Sub MyTrim()
Const STARTS_WITH_STR As String = "Direct Credit"
Const TRIM_NUM As Integer = 21

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim range As range
Dim cell As range
Dim sText As String
Dim iPos As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set sht = ActiveSheet

' loop for 1000 rows
For i = 1 To 1000
    ' for each row, get the cell in column "B"
    Set cell = sht.Cells(i, "B")
    ' get the text of the cell with triming blanks on both side of the string
    sText = Trim(cell.Text)

    ' Search for a sub string. It does a text based compare (vbTextCompare)
    ' meaning- it will look for "Direct Credit" and also for "DIRECT CREDIT" and
    ' every thing in between (for example: DIREct Credit, .....)
    iPost = InStr(1, sText, STARTS_WITH_STR, vbTextCompare)

    ' if the cell starts with the sub string above
    If (iPos = 1) Then
        ' remove the 21 first chars
        sText = Mid(sText, TRIM_NUM + 1)
        cell.Value = sText
    End If
Next
End Sub
```